# Expected value of the electric field operator in the superposition of two number states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, superposition

Good morning everyone!

I have recently started a course of introductory quantum optics, but unfortunately by quantum mechanics background is not very good - so I'm having some problems when it comes to actual calculations. For example, I've done some exercises on this superposition of two number states of a single mode field:
$$
|\psi \rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|n\rangle+e^{i\phi}|n+1\rangle)
$$

I have managed, following the professor's calculations, to calculate the variance of the photon number:
$$
\Delta \hat{N}^2=\langle\hat{N}^2\rangle-\langle\hat{N}\rangle^2=\frac{1}{4}
$$

Now, I want to calculate the expected value of the electric field in this state, but all the help I find online is about wave functions.
I know that the expected value is:
$$
\langle\hat{E}\rangle=\langle\psi|\hat{E}|\psi\rangle
$$

And that I could split it into:
$$
\langle\hat{E}\rangle=\langle\hat{E}^+\rangle+\langle\hat{E}^{-}\rangle
$$

But how do I actually calculate this? What do I integrate over?

I know this may look like I'm just asking for homework help but I really just want to learn how these work in general.
Thanks a lot if you take the time to reply!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what $\hat E^+$ and $\hat E^-$ are?

Comment: They are the positive and negative frequencies of the amplitude of the electric field (maybe these terms are more often associated with quantum optics and not general mechanics, sorry for giving them for granted)